# Error 438 object doesn't support this property

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have this macro that works on my office computer but when I run it at a client's computer It doesn't work and shows the

> Error 438 object doesn't support this property

marking this line:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E2:E" & nFilas)
```

(My excel version is 365 and the client's is 2013)

I've tried changing `Worksheets` by `Sheets`, `ActiveWorkbook` by `Sheet` but nothing worked.

```
Columns("E:G").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$E$1:$G$" & nFilas).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), _
    Header:=xlYes
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("E2:E" & nFilas) _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:X" & nFilas)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: what does nFilas equate to when the code is run?

Comment: Change `.Add2` into `.Add` I think `.Add2` was introduced in a later Excel version. • Also you might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: nFilas is the lenght of the rows in column.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.Add2` into `.Add` I think `.Add2` was introduced in a later Excel version.

I recommend the following improvement:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")

ws.Range("$E$1:$G$" & nFilas).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
With ws.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("E2:E" & nFilas), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:X" & nFilas)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```